# Programmatically setting .eps files to CMYK (as opposed to RGB)

Tags: vector, vector-graphics, eps, inkscape

We have an app where we need to export files from vector files from Inkscape to .eps to be used for printing.   While this is working fine, our printers have complained that they are receiving the files in RGB mode instead of CMYK.

Is there a way to programmatically set .eps files to CMYK document color mode?

Answer (score 1):

Color mode isn't a setting like, say, DPI. Converting from RGB to CMYK for printing is a complex process, often involving color spaces, halftoning, and other nontrivial algorithms.

Comment: No, it looks like colorjizz would not be helpful in this regard. Can you just get inkscape to output in CMYK?